# How to use scanf to collect float to array

Tags: c, codeblocks

The code is looking like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i,n,m;
    printf("Input Size of Array : ");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    float number[m];
    for(i=0;i<m;i++){
        n = n+1;
        printf("Number %d : ",n);
        scanf("%f", &number[i]);
    }
    printf("\nNumber in Order => ");
    for(i=0;i<m;i++){
        printf("%.2f ", &number[i]);
    }
}
```

In the end. The output is 0.00 0.00 0.00 .....

So Why did **scanf** not collecting any float to an array? How do I fix this?

Comment: you also need to initialize `n`. Surely `printf("Number %d : ",n);` is showing you garbage. Better yet, get rid of `n` entirely and use `i` instead: `printf("Number %d : ", i+1);`

Comment: Using user input for VLA dimension without any range check is an absolutely "no go"

Comment: OT: `int i,n,m;` --> `unsigned int int i, n=0, m;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You invoked *undefined behavior* by passind data having wrong type at the line

```c
printf("%.2f ", &number[i]);
```

`%f` expects `double`, but `&number[i]` has type `float*`.

Remove the `&` and pass the floating-point value to `printf`. (`float` as variable-length arguments will automatically converted to `double`)

Also another *undefined behavior* is invoked at the line

```c
n = n+1;
```

because the value of `n` is used without being initialized.

One more point is that you should check the return value of `scanf()` to check if it succeeded to read expected number of values.

Fixed code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i,n = 0,m; /* initialize n */
    printf("Input Size of Array : ");
    if(scanf("%d",&m)!=1){ /* check if scanf() succeeded */
        fputs("read error\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    float number[m];
    for(i=0;i<m;i++){
        n = n+1;
        printf("Number %d : ",n);
        if(scanf("%f", &number[i])!=1){ /* check if scanf() succeeded */
            fputs("read error\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    printf("\nNumber in Order => ");
    for(i=0;i<m;i++){
        printf("%.2f ", number[i]); /* remove extra & */
    }
}
```